# ¿Como hacer que este control de imágenes en Android afecte solo al id deseado?

Tags: php, mysql, android

estoy teniendo dificultades al intentar que esta función solo afecte al producto (id) especificado, se trata de un control de imágenes de productos para un inventario realizado con Android Studio, MySQL y PHP. El codigo funciona, pero solo he logrado que la inserte en una columna nueva o que actualice todos los productos existentes, mas no un id en especifico.

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {

 $DefaultId = 0;

 $ImageData = $_POST['image_data'];

 $ImageName = $_POST['image_tag'];

 $ImagePath = "upload/$ImageName.jpg";

 $ServerURL = "192.168.1.3/$ImagePath";

 $InsertSQL = "UPDATE producto SET imagen = '".$ServerURL. "'";

 if(mysqli_query($conexion, $InsertSQL)){

 file_put_contents($ImagePath,base64_decode($ImageData));

 echo "La imagen ha sido cargada con éxito.";
 }

 mysqli_close($conexion);
 }else{
 echo "Por favor, intente de nuevo.";
 }
?>
```

Con este código php sube la imagen actualizando todos los productos (no es lo que quiero), y al agregar la condición de codproducto = $codproducto aun cuando se define antes, tira el error de que el index codproducto no esta definido.

Esta es mi primera pregunta, si necesitan el código java de android studio me lo hacen saber por favor.

EDIT 1:
**Estructura de la tabla producto**
[image: Estructura de la tabla producto]

**Codigo Java:**

Si se fijan, cree un método "buscarproducto2", ya que en previas actividades he podido realizar modificaciones primero buscando el id y luego modificando, pero como este código es tan diferente y largo, no he podido encontrarle solución con la búsqueda del producto.

```
public class Pantalla_SubirImagen extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText buscador_codproducto2, nombre_producto2;
    Button buscador2;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;

    Button GetImageFromGalleryButton, UploadImageOnServerButton;

    ImageView ShowSelectedImage;

    EditText imageName;

    Bitmap FixBitmap;

    String ImageTag = "image_tag" ;

    String ImageName = "image_data" ;

    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream ;

    byte[] byteArray ;

    String ConvertImage ;

    String GetImageNameFromEditText;

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection ;

    URL url;

    OutputStream outputStream;

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;

    int RC ;

    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;

    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    boolean check = true;

    private int GALLERY = 1, CAMERA = 2;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subir_imagen);

        buscador_codproducto2 = findViewById(R.id.buscador2);
        nombre_producto2 = findViewById(R.id.nombre_producto2);

        buscador2 = findViewById(R.id.buscar_producto2);

        GetImageFromGalleryButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSelect);

        UploadImageOnServerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        ShowSelectedImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        imageName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.imageName);

        buscador2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                buscarProducto2("http://192.168.1.3/Buscar_Producto_Imagen.php?codproducto=" + buscador_codproducto2.getText() + "");
            }
        });



        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        GetImageFromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                showPictureDialog();


            }
        });


        UploadImageOnServerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                GetImageNameFromEditText = imageName.getText().toString();


                UploadImageToServer();

            }
        });

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Pantalla_SubirImagen.this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                        5);
            }
        }
    }

    private void buscarProducto2(String URL) {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {

                        jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        nombre_producto2.setText(jsonObject.getString("nombre_producto"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de sistema", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        );

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    }

    private void showPictureDialog(){
        AlertDialog.Builder pictureDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        pictureDialog.setTitle("Select Action");
        String[] pictureDialogItems = {
                "Photo Gallery",
                "Camera" };
        pictureDialog.setItems(pictureDialogItems,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        switch (which) {
                            case 0:
                                choosePhotoFromGallary();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                takePhotoFromCamera();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
        pictureDialog.show();
    }
    public void choosePhotoFromGallary() {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY);
    }

    private void takePhotoFromCamera() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            return;
        }
        if (requestCode == GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                Uri contentURI = data.getData();
                try {
                    FixBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), contentURI);
                    // String path = saveImage(bitmap);
                    //Toast.makeText(Pantalla_SubirImagen.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
                    UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(Pantalla_SubirImagen.this, "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA) {
            FixBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ShowSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(FixBitmap);
            UploadImageOnServerButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //  saveImage(thumbnail);
            //Toast.makeText(ShadiRegistrationPart5.this, "Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void UploadImageToServer(){

        FixBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);

        byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

        ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

        class AsyncTaskUploadClass extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Pantalla_SubirImagen.this,"La imagen se esta cargando.","Por favor, espere.",false,false);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1) {

                super.onPostExecute(string1);

                progressDialog.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(Pantalla_SubirImagen.this,string1,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

                ImageProcessClass imageProcessClass = new ImageProcessClass();

                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();

                HashMapParams.put(ImageTag, GetImageNameFromEditText);

                HashMapParams.put(ImageName, ConvertImage);

                String FinalData = imageProcessClass.ImageHttpRequest("http://192.168.1.3/upload-image-to-server.php", HashMapParams);

                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskUploadClass AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ = new AsyncTaskUploadClass();
        AsyncTaskUploadClassOBJ.execute();
    }

    public class ImageProcessClass{

        public String ImageHttpRequest(String requestURL,HashMap<String, String> PData) {

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                url = new URL(requestURL);

                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);

                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                        new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));

                bufferedWriter.flush();

                bufferedWriter.close();

                outputStream.close();

                RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));

                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String RC2;

                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){

                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet()) {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilder.append("&");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

                stringBuilder.append("=");

                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 5) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Now user should be able to use camera

            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(Pantalla_SubirImagen.this, "No se puede usar la Camara, modifique los permisos de camara", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Pantalla:**

Se introduce el codproducto, busca el nombre para verificar si existe, pero no lo puedo relacionar con subir la imagen.

[image: Pantalla]

Comment: Podrías publicar la estructura de la tabla de la DB? La condición la ponés con un `WHERE` al final del `UPDATE`? Editá tu pregunta mostrando como lo estás haciendo y el error exacto que obtenés.

Comment: Hola **micco35** El código que muestras en PHP, solo hace el Update del dato que recibe en el POST, por lo que, el problema debe de estar en como y de donde estas mandado la información. Si puedes subir subir ese código seria de ayuda, tambien indicar donde escribes y declaras esto **codproducto = $codproducto**

Comment: Ya subi creo que todo lo necesario, al comienzo temia que era mucha informacion pero alli esta todo, les agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Tienes que recuperar el código del producto que pasas en la URL, haciendo algo así: `$codProducto=$_POST["codproducto"];` y luego usarlo como filtro en la consulta, por ejemplo: `UPDATE producto SET imagen = '$ServerURL' WHERE codproducto=$codProducto` Si no funciona es porque los datos no están llegando correctamente desde Android. Puedes hacer un `var_dump($_POST);` para verificar qué datos están llegando y cómo llegan.

Comment: Si tienes razon, creo que los datos no están llegando correctamente desde Android. Si te fijas en el codigo Java, solo estoy recuperando el codproducto en la busqueda del producto, que al insertar el codproducto me muestra el nombre para verificar que existe, como haria para recuperar ese mismo codproducto al darle al boton "Subir" (UploadImageOnServerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload) ?